# JavaFX setStageToScene() makes Labels display ellipsis

Tags: javafx

Instead of re-sizing the stage to give the labels enough room to display all of the text, the text is just cut off and turned into "..." If I manually make the stage larger, then the text expands and displays correctly.

Is there any way to have the stage automatically re-sized to show all the text?

Comment: There is no such method as `setStageToScene()`.  Edit your question to include an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: There is not a short automatic way to resize the stage to fit the content of the scene that will work perfectly, you can do it programatically. Also if I were you I would set a minimum width(maybe height as well) to the stage and all the components such as buttons, labels and so, because otherwise when you resize the window manually they get resized as well and you won't be able to see the text.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I realized that I miss-typed my title, its supposed to be Stage.setSizeToScene().

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer after a bit. The labels were instantiated as empty, so setSizeToScene() made the Stage fit empty Labels into the Stage. When the Labels were changed with setText(), they were bigger than when the Stage fit them in so they displayed Ellipsis.

The fix was to call setSizeToScene() after the Labels were filled out.